# How to make CSS hover tooltip display auto position(Top,Right,Bottom,Left) inside of a table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 and custom CSS,I want to display a tooltip on td element and position it top or right or bottom or left up to the positon of td element  ? Here you can find my classes with a HTML file and a CSS file that make it's position always on top.

Here I enclose my code link to you:
[Here is my Codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BePzNO)

Below you will find my code which does not provide the right solution.

**This is some HTML code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-6">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <td class="CellWithComment">
                    S
                    <span class="CellComment">
                        010620190528113002
                        <br>
                            55555
                        <br>
                        2019-05-2804:25:37
                    </span>
                <td>
                <td class="CellWithComment">
                    S
                    <span class="CellComment">
                        010620190528113002
                        <br>
                            55555
                        </br>
                        2019-05-2804:25:37
                    </span>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is my CSS:**

```
.CellWithComment {
 position: relative;
 }

.CellComment {
visibility: hidden;
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 3px 7px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1908;
bottom: 100%;
margin-left: -92px;
}
.CellComment::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.CellWithComment:hover span.CellComment {
 visibility: visible;
 }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: am I correct to assume that you want the tooltip to be _fully_ visible if the tooltip is displayed 1)  on a far right element, 2) at the bottom of the table, instead of being cut because the tooltip is going outside the visible area of the page?

Comment: I just updated my question and codepen to make it clear

Comment: I already found the solutions, Here is my code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qGQjaW

Comment: Nicely done, but your HTML code is still broken. Check so that you close all your `TD` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I think it's usefull for you.

```
.CellComment:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #000000;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

.CellComment {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 3px 7px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1908;
 top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something fancy, you need to use javascript. Here is what I came up with:

First of all. You're HTML is incorrect, where you never finish the `<td>` with `</td>` but instead adding another `<td>`. I had to fix that before I moved on with adding more code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBKzZB

```
.CellWithComment:last-child > .CellComment {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background-color: #cc00cc;
}

tr:last-child > .CellWithComment > .CellComment {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  background-color: #00cccc;
}

tr:last-child > .CellWithComment:last-child  > .CellComment {
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(20deg, #00cccc 50%, #cc00cc 51%);
}
```

I added a `background-color` so it's easier to see my idea behind my solution.